# Why is my User Group Information Do as not passing my keytab token to my HDFS access method

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs, kerberos

When I attempt to list the files in a HDFS directory I am receiving the following error:

```
main] ERROR com.pr.hdfs.common.hadooputils.HdfsUtil - Failed to connect to hdfs directory /HDFS/Datastore/DB
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
```

The code I am using although being accessed as scala is the following Java:

```
public static List<Path> listHdfsFilePaths(final FileSystem hdfs, final String directory) throws IOException
 {
  final List<Path> result = new ArrayList<>();
  final FileStatus[] fileStatuses;
  try
  {
     fileStatuses = hdfs.listStatus(new Path(directory));
     for (final FileStatus fileStatus : fileStatuses)
     {
        result.add(fileStatus.getPath());
     }
  }
  catch (final IOException e)
  {
     LOGGER.error("Failed to connect to hdfs directory " + directory, e);
     throw e;
  }
  return result;
}
```

The scala code wraps a User Group Information doas to access the folder:

```
val auctions = ugiDoAs(ugi){
  val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConf)
  HdfsUtils.listHdfsFilePaths(hdfs, "/HDFS/Datastore/DB/")
}
```

The ugiDoAs method is specified as:

```
def ugiDoAs[T](ugi: Option[UserGroupInformation])(code: => T) = ugi match {
   case None => code
   case Some(u) => u.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction[T] {
     override def run(): T = code
   })
 }
```

The ugiDoAs wrapper works for reading from Zookeeper, reading from Hbase but just not accessing HDFS in this case.

Also, my ugi variable contains the keytab and the principal needed.

Comment: have you used  your keytab file to authenticate and run hdfs commands to verify there is no issue with keytab file by using kinit -kt [your-key-tab]

Comment: Hi, the same keytab file has been used via kinit -kt, and also to authenticate reading from Zookeeper and Hbase.

Comment: so to confirm, you can authenticate using the keytab file and use the ticket to run hdfs commands without a problem?

Comment: Yep, `$ kinit -kt /opt/hdfs/conf/keytab/hdfs.keytab user_K
$ hadoop fs -ls /
Found 5 items`